# How do I make my camera in my main scene move using buttons in an overlay UI scene?

Tags: game-engine, camera, logic-bricks

My logic bricks for the camera in the main scene are set up as follows:
[image]

And the logic bricks for the buttons in the interface are: 
[image]

I'm not sure what is wrong with these, but this wont move the camera at all in the main scene.

Comment: My blend file is here:
[<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1195" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1195/)

It's a mess but we're looking at "Scene", object is "Camera" and GUI the four diamond buttons in the corner.

Answer (score 2):

## GUI

Get rid of the "moving" logic (not needed with the below method)

Replace all property actuators with message actuators. Choose meaningful subject names, such as "move forward".

Enable <kbd>True Level Triggering</kbd> at the according sensors to send the messages as long as the operation is requested (-> the key is pressed).

## Camera

Replace all property sensors with message sensors e.g. listening on "move forward".

## Remarks:

- Interobject connections are not needed.
- You can have as many object serving as UI as you want
- UI objects can reside in any active scene.

I hope it helps

Comment: It's still not working, I added keyboard sensors to the Camera but i specifically need it to work through a user interface. The screenshots are here https://www.dropbox.com/s/qgotfxlkgwoc1lc/Screenshot%20from%202016-04-13%2020%3A03%3A17.png?dl=0 and https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=Screenshot+from+2016-04-13+20%3A02%3A01.png  . I tried it with having the level options on the sensor selected too but it didn't work either.

Comment: You do not need to add keyboard sensors to the camera. You add them to a separate "keyboard.UI" object which sends the same messages as your "virtual buttons" objects.